# execute sql query on sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I have the following SQL query being executed in MySQL. How do I turn this query into a query in Sequelize format.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   weather_datas AS S 
WHERE  created_at = (SELECT Max(created_at) 
                     FROM   weather_datas 
                     WHERE  control_esp_id = S.control_esp_id 
                     GROUP  BY control_esp_id)
```

Comment: What did you already try?
Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

may be this can get data you wanted

```
await weather_datas.findAll({
  attributes: [[Sequelize.fn('max', Sequelize.col('created_at')), 'max']],
  group: ['control_esp_id'],
  where : {
   control_esp_id : req.body.control_esp_id}
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But there is an error in S.control_esp_id "SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer"

Comment: check I have updated the answer you have to add `object` or `req` instead of `req.body `from where you are getting the `control_esp_id` so it can compare both id's